# Проверка на изменение значения в БД с интервалом во времени на PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую, господа! Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее хочу сказать, что буду очень благодарен человеку, который сможет грамотно ответить! Заранее спасибо! Итак. У нас есть база данных, в ней есть таблица, в которой по умолчанию стоит значение 0, необходим скрипт, который проверяет данную таблицу каждые 5-10 секунд, и если значение поменяется на 1, то необходимо вывести сообщение. Прошу помочь. Спасибо большое!

Comment: ,то необходимо вывести сообщение.  - а куда собственно вынести?

Comment: Я планировал сделать программу в PHP Devel Studio,которая будет открывать картинку при изменении запроса.

Comment: Сдается мне, велосипед на Троих соображаете. ) Напишите лучше, зачем это вам с точки обычной логики?

Comment: @Ale_x,могу объяснить.Если вам не сложно,предоставьте скайп или вк.Спасибо.

Comment: так всем напиши, вопрос обнови.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript (для AJAX подключите jquery):**

```
var cur_timer = setInterval(function() {  
  $.ajax({

    type:     'POST',

    dataType: 'json',

    cache:    false,

    timeout:  10000,

    data:     'action=check',

    url:      '/ajax.php',

    success:  function(answer){

        if(answer.check) { alert(СООБЩЕНИЕ); clearInterval(cur_timer ); }

    }

});

}, 10000);
```

**php(ajax.php):**

```
if($_POST('action')=='check'){

$answer['check'] = false;

???ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БД???

$result=mysql_query("SELECT check FROM таблица");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {

if(mysql_result($result,0,check)==1) {

$answer['check'] = true;

}

}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($answer);

}
```

ps: это общий принцип такой проверки, мелочи допишите сами в зависимости от ваших задач! писал на скорую... могут быть синтаксические ошибки

Comment: Огроменное спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Это в сторону JS и AJAX крутить надо, примеров в нете полно, по запросу: таймеры js+php (в этой комбинации)

Comment: Реализовать на PHP необходимо.

Comment: Если вам нужно без обновления страницы это всё делать нужно, то лучше прислушайтесь к совету @Manitikyl

Comment: @MasterAlex
Мне необходимо реализовать данный скрипт в PHP Devel Studio...

Comment: @Влад Иванов, дайте угадаю: ездить вы хотите на самолете, а летать на велосипеде? Область применения PHP в вашем понимании предоставьте, будьте добры.